# Create EC2's AMI with installed softwares and server configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

Our customer asked us to migrate our soft from on-premise to his AWS environment.
So to test this we made this in our own AWS account to ensure that it's working, we have now a working soft in our account.

Is it possible to create an image or anything of our environment with installed soft and/or libraries to prevent us from going through the deployment phase again?

Comment: just to confirm,when you say env you mean ec2 enivrinment?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra Yup, question edited

Comment: Posted a solution on how to create ami and its cost structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your requirements i am assuming you have already installed all the required software and libraries on your ec2.

So in order to avoid creating that environment again you can create AMI for your ec2 instance.

according to [docs](https://You%20can%20launch%20an%20instance%20from%20an%20existing%20AMI,%20customize%20the%20instance%20(for%20example,%20install%20software%20on%20the%20instance),%20and%20then%20save%20this%20updated%20configuration%20as%20a%20custom%20AMI.%20Instances%20launched%20from%20this%20new%20custom%20AMI%20include%20the%20customizations%20that%20you%20made%20when%20you%20created%20the%20AMI.)

> You can launch an instance from an existing AMI, customize the instance (for example, install software on the instance), and then save this updated configuration as a custom AMI. Instances launched from this new custom AMI include the customizations that you made when you created the AMI.

follow these steps to [create ami using console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/tkv-create-ami-from-instance.html).After creating Ami, you can launch ec2 directly from AMI or ec2 launch menu by selecting your custom ami.

Note: AMI's are stored in s3 so you will charged for storage in s3 and once your work is done you can register it.